# Gson not able to parse Array. But it is json array

Tags: android, json, gson

**I have the following json string:**

```
{"objKampfEntry":[{"deffSpielerId":"9","kampfId":"7","offSpielerId":"10","rundeCounter":"0","rundenList":[{"deffIsReady":"0","deffMove":"0","deffSpieler":{"ausdauer":"5","eiId":"0","gesichtId":"normal","helm":"0","id":"13","kraft":"6","leben":"12","lebenMax":"50","level":"1","name":"Test","niederlagen":"0","punkte":"1","rang":"1","rustung":"0","siege":"0","timestamp":"1397385595686","waffe":"0"},"done":"0","kampfId":"7","offIsReady":"1","offMove":"0","offSpieler":{"ausdauer":"5","eiId":"0","gesichtId":"normal","helm":"0","id":"14","kraft":"6","leben":"12","lebenMax":"50","level":"1","name":"Test2","niederlagen":"0","punkte":"1","rang":"1","rustung":"0","siege":"0","timestamp":"1397385841118","waffe":"0"},"rundeNr":"0","winner":"0"}]}]}
```

**If I use**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type listOfKampfEntry = new TypeToken<List<ObjKampfEntry>>(){}.getType();
ArrayList<ObjKampfEntry> list = gson.fromJson(json, listOfKampfEntry);
```

**I get this error:**

```
04-13 12:45:48.706: W/System.err(4411): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
04-13 12:45:48.706: W/System.err(4411):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
04-13 12:45:48.706: W/System.err(4411):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
04-13 12:45:48.706: W/System.err(4411):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
```

**So I have an array of objKampfEntry and inside an array of rundenList. What am I doing wrong?**

My ObjKampfEntry class:

```
public class ObjKampfEntry {

    private long kampfId;
    private long offSpielerId;
    private long deffSpielerId;

    private int rundeCounter;

    private ArrayList<Runde> rundenList = new ArrayList<Runde>();
    //constructor and getter/setter

}
```

And the runde object

```
public class Runde {

    private long kampfId;
    private long winner;
    private int rundeNr;
    private int offIsReady;
    private int deffIsReady;
    private int done;
    private Spieler offSpieler;
    private Spieler deffSpieler;
    private int offMove;
    private int deffMove;
...
```

Here the Spieler object

```
public abstract class ACharakter {

    protected long id;
    protected String name;
    protected int leben;
    protected int lebenMax;
    protected int kraft;
    protected int ausdauer;

public class Spieler extends ACharakter {

    private int rang;
    private int level;
    private int punkte;
    private long timestamp;
    private int waffe;
    private int rustung;
    private int helm;
    private int siege;
    private int niederlagen;
    private int eiId;
    private String gesichtId;
```

Comment: Post Spieler.java code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input is *not* a JSON array of `ObjKampfEntry` objects. Instead, it is a JSON *object* with one key/value pair whose value is a JSON array of `ObjKampfEntry` objects.

The "correct" input according to your scheme would be `[{"deffSpielerId":"9","kampfId":"7",...}]`, as that will indeed map to a `List<ObjKampfEntry>`. If you can't change the input, then you'll need another class holding one field named `objKampfEntry` of type `List<ObjKampfEntry>`:

```
public class ObjKampfEntries {

    private ArrayList<ObjKampfEntry> objKampfEntry = new ArrayList<ObjKampfEntry>();

}

ObjKampfEntries entries = gson.fromJson(json, ObjKampfEntries.class);
List<ObjKampfEntry> list = entries.objKampfEntry;
```